# numpy element transformation with lambda?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

In a 3D numpy array, I need to transform each element as follows: if it's less that 0, it must be become 0, if it's greater than 255, it must be become 255, and remain as-is otherwise.

How can I achieve that with numpy? I am thinking of something like

```
img.transform_each(transform_func)
```

where

```
def transform_func(x):
    if x<0:
        return 0;
    # etc
```

Is there any build-function like `transform_each` for that?
I don't what to make for-for-for loop manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`clip`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) to keep the values of an array within a particular range. For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([-1, 23, 312, 47, -5])
>>> a.clip(0, 255)
array([  0,  23, 255,  47,   0])
```

The returns a new array of the same shape containing the values - you'll need to reassign `a` to this new array if you want to make the changes permanent or else use the `out` parameter to perform the operation in place:

```
np.clip(a, 0, 255, out=a)
```

An alternative approach which opens the way to more complex operations is the idea of boolean indexing.

For example, to set elements of an array `a` which are less than `0` to `0`:

```
a[a < 0] = 0
```

Or to multiply all values of `2` by `7`, you can write:

```
a[a == 2] *= 7
```

Comment: This is even better! Will accept in 7 minutes.
But what if the transformation is more complex? I believe the sources will tell me, but if you know already, please share this info too.

Comment: Glad it's what you're looking for! It returns an array of the same dimensions if that's what you mean - if `a` is 3D, so is the clipped array.

Comment: Actually no, what I'm asking is what if I need not to clip, but some custom transformation, something like "if element is 5, replace it with 2, otherwise multiply by 4"?

Comment: Ah - no `clip` can't do that, it just limits the values to a particular range. You'd be better off using using boolean indexing for transformations like the one you describe.

Comment: @IlyaSmagin: I've edited my answer to include a brief description of boolean indexing and how it can be applied.